# List of values not showing up in sg.Combo drop down list in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, pysimplegui

My code below does not show the list specified (based on parsing excel file dataframe columns) and the drop down list is empty.I am unsure of what I am missing here, please could someone help out? Thanks

Here is a example:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir


header_list=[]
layout = [ [sg.Text('Browse to file:'), sg.Input(size=(20,1), key='input'),sg.FileBrowse (key='filebrowse'),
            sg.Button('Accept')],
           [sg.Text('Choose a header')],
           [sg.Combo(header_list, size=(20,1),enable_events= True, key='DROP')],
           [sg.Cancel()]]

window = sg.Window('Choose the col', layout)
event, values = window.Read()

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Accept':
        inputfile = values['filebrowse']
        df = pd.read_excel(inputfile, header=None)
        #print(df)
        data = df.values.tolist()  
        header_list = df.iloc[0].tolist()
        #print(header_list2)
        data = df[1:].values.tolist()
        window['DROP'].update([header_list][0])

window.Close()
```

Comment: Your variable `header` is `[]` and that is what you used to create your Combobox.  You never updated the element inside your event loop.  You only changed the variable `header`.  The `update` method will change the value. It's a really basic part of PySimpleGUI.

Comment: thanks @MikeyB! I have managed to get them to show (updated code above to reflect this change)  however it is showing all the columns as one list. How can I change it so each option appears as a drop down list and the one selected can be used for further processing?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work after adding `enable_events=True` in the sg.Button

```
layout = [ [sg.Text('Browse to file:'), sg.Input(size=(20,1), key='input'),sg.FileBrowse (key='filebrowse'),
            sg.Button('Accept', enable_events=True)],
```

and adding values=[header_list][0] to the update method

```
window['DROP'].update(values=[header_list][0])
```